# What is the order of stopping services when application is stopped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have many service hosted application. It contains `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. They hosted with the method `AddHostedService`:

```
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
         services.AddHostedService<ServiceA>();
         services.AddHostedService<ServiceB>();
    });

using (var host = hostBuilder.Build())
{
    host.Start();
    host.WaitForShutdown();
}
```

I know what the `ServiceB` will be runned after the ServiceA has been started. What is the order of stopping services? Will the `ServiceA` stop guaranteed after stopping the `ServiceB`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementations of `IHostedService` are *started* in the order they're added ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L42)):

> ```
> _hostedServices = Services.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();
>
> foreach (var hostedService in _hostedServices)
> {
>     // Fire IHostedService.Start
>     await hostedService.StartAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
> }
> ```

In the snippet above, `Services.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>()` retrieves all implementations of `IHostedService` from the DI container, as an `IEnumerable<T>`. These are ordered by when they were registered.

Implementations of `IHostedService` are *stopped* in **reverse** order ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L70)):

> ```
> foreach (var hostedService in _hostedServices.Reverse())
> {
>     // ...
>
>     await hostedService.StopAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

In your example scenario, `ServiceA` will *start* before `ServiceB`, but it will *stop* **after** `ServiceB`.